Statistical models with values in non-freely generated R-modules
Setup
My general understanding of most statistical models is something like: a type of model for $n$ variables is a vector space $V$ and a function
$$E: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n) \times V \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} $$
where the power set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is where our sample measurements live, $V$ is where the coefficients of our model live, and $E$ compute the ``error''. Often for a fixed sample $S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we just minimize $E(S, -)$.
Example
$S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the set of points $S = \{ (0,1), (1,2), (3,10)\}$ and a vector $\beta = (b,m)$ corresponds to a line $y= mx+b$ and my error function usual sum of squares of errors. Then this model returns the least squares.
Question
Allowing me to pretend this is correct: what are examples where the model's coefficients naturally land in a non-freely generated module? i.e. not a vector space? i.e. something where there is only a chance to resolve with a chain complex of vector spaces?
Motivation
This question.

I am not sure I follow. To me, a statistical model is a family of probability measures. Write $\mathcal{P}$ for a statistical model. Even if it is parametric in the sense that $\mathcal{P} = {P_{\theta}}_{\theta \in \Theta}$, it is always YOU who set what the $\Theta$ is. If you need $\Theta$ to be a vector space, go for it. If you want it to be literally anything else, nothing is stopping you from doing it. There is no such a thing as what $\Theta$ should naturally be.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you @温泽海. In my example, I gave an idea of what I was trying to describe. But that model could look like $y = e^{(\beta_1 \cdot x_1 + \beta_2 \cdot x_2)} \cdot \beta_{3} \cdot x_3$, solving then for the $\beta$'s, or any other (higher dimensional) surface I'm fitting to my data. I am probably using the wrong words at the beginning (like maybe this isn't a "statistical model"). Feel free to help :)

The definitions are a bit weird (e.g. no reason for observations to be real numbers, you'd typically speak of likelihood rather than error), but I think there are some real-world examples where the parameters do not form a vector space (or at least not a natural one). The topological stuff is a bit over my head, so not sure if those are actually what you are after....

In computational phylogenetics, $V$ is typically the space of trees over known set of vertices with positive weight for each edge. I don't think you can impose vector space structure here (or at least not a very useful one)

$V$ could be a small finite set

$V$ could contain values with differing dimensions (e.g. when both the number and location of clusters is treated as unknown in k-means, see also Chinese restaurant process )



Thank you for not getting hung up on my naive framing! I think your suggestion is in line with what I'm looking for. Specifically the first bullet. There it seems I have a space of trees over vertices with weights, and I could maybe think about the decorating the tree edges with weights as a vector in a level of a chain complex (decorating vertices would be another level and decorating triangles in a higher dimensional "tree" would be another). Cool, thanks!

Also, there are examples of a manifold that isn't a vector space, such as $S^1$ for a wind direction or $S^2$ for an earthquake epicenter, or whatever the quotient space is for lines without orientation (seismography) or axial frames without orientation. These could all be embedded in a suitable $\mathbb{R}^d$, of course.
